# Can I select 2 field as index in Pivot Table in Excel?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am trying to create a pivot table in excel which taking 2 fields as column and be the key for grouping data.

Example:
Original Table:
| Fruit | Country | Sold |
| -------- | ---- | --|
| Apple    | USA| 10|
| Apple   | JAPAN| 20|
| Orange| JAPAN|5|
| Orange| USA|3|
| Orange| JAPAN|100|
| Orange| THAILAND|30|
| Banana| THAILAND|20|
| Banana| THAILAND|10|

Pivot Table I want:
| Fruit | Country | TotalSold |
| ------| ---- | --|
| Apple | USA  | 10|
| Apple | JAPAN| 20|
| Orange| JAPAN|105|
| Orange| USA  |3|
| Orange| THAILAND|30|
| Banana| THAILAND|30|

Basically, I want to use 2 column as key to group the Sold Amount. I have played a while in excel and still cannot find a way to group the data in this way.

Comment: I don't understand. If you put Fruit and Country in the Rows field and Sum of Sold in the Values field that gives you what you want.

Comment: @JosWoolley If I put both in Row field, the Country will be under Fruit but not in a separate column.